# Building a secure contact form

Tags: php, ajax, validation, contact-form

I'm building a `contact form` (PHP file, design has been already made) which will communicate with the PHP via `AJAX`. I need to secure the contact form to deny any spam, for the client side, I'll be using [`ReCaptcha`](http://recaptcha.net/) for the validation on client side ... But, how can I secure the script from being tampered with or sending arbitrary codes?

I mean, if the spammer/hacker uses the form and submits a PHP code that could affect the server, how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What are you doing with the user input which could cause submitted PHP to "affect the server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text that has been entered in your contact form should never be executed, only passed along in an e-mail message. So, whatever a hacker would submit, the worst it should be able to do is show up in the mailbox behind the form.

It's also always a good idea to use `htmlentities` on the content sent from your contact form, so if any HTML characters are used, they can't do any harm.

Comment: Ok, that is great ... But, this doesn't validate the user input! I need 2 do 2 step validation, user side and client side.

Comment: just in case the user disables the JS

Comment: @sikas — What does the input need validating for?

Comment: This is a contact form ... it will have email, phone number (this may be entered in various ways) a message, name and a Recaptcha

Comment: @sikas — How does your complaint about this answer not addressing input validation relate to your question which is about security?

Comment: "It's also always a good idea to use htmlentities on the content sent from your contact form, so if any HTML characters are used, they can't do any harm." — No it isn't. It is essential to run it over use input that is being *placed in an HTML document*, but not for most other purposes. Use database escaping techniques before inserting it into a database. Ensure it doesn't break MIME boundaries before inserting it into an email. Don't just throw htmlentnties are any user input.

Answer (score 0):

[have a read](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-blunders-2/)

[Validate form with php](http://buildinternet.com/2008/12/how-to-validate-a-form-complete-with-error-messages-using-php-part-1/)

Comment: This article is great, but it is only talking about securing the DB though.

Comment: added another link on validating forms in php